# How can I find coordinates of possible points a given distance away from a given point?

Tags: javascript, math, distance

I'm working on designing a HTML5 canvas test that needs to have two circles at a fixed distance apart but the locations are randomized on each completion of the test. My plan is to keep one of the circles at pre-set locations and find random locations for the other circle.

I'd like to find a list of points a given distance away from a given point as a possible location of center of the other circle. Basically the points on the circumference of a circle with the given point as the center and given distance as radius. Is there any jquery or javascript math function that already does this or will I have to figure out a way to solve the distance formula equation below ?

[image: Distance Formula]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @popnoodles - I'll post there, thanks! I did clarify the OP a bit to indicate that I'm working on a programming problem that requires this bit of math.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Why not put it at the average of the other center and the far 2 corners?

Comment: You can flag your question for it to be moved, rather than posting twice. Anyway, simply translating it into code would be faster than waiting for an answer for more than 8 hours.

Comment: use polar coordinates centered at $(x_1, y_1)$ then convert back to cartesian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the centre of a fixed circle (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>), a formula for a uniformly distributed random circle centre of distance *r* from (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>) is simply:

(x<sub>0</sub> + *r* * cosθ,y<sub>0</sub> + *r* * sinθ)

where θ is uniformly distributed over [0,2π). That takes one line of code to create the random angle, and one line to perform those calculations. That's a whopping two lines of code... Of course you'll realise immediately that this formula doesn't require (x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub>) to be fixed, so you can just as easily add a third line of code randomising its position at every iteration, and then calculate the random point.

When generalising to higher dimensions (a uniform point on an N-sphere), polar co-ordinates are no longer very useful. There are simple methods that take only 5 lines of code to implement, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html.